# Javascript Parsing with Bing Maps

Tags: javascript

I am currently using Bing Maps and getting returned the value of Lat/Lon but I want to parse out the following.

http://www.pastie.org/private/stz7u3cgvpn4g4evmheoq

The second results of the location that includes the AddressLine, Locality, PostalTown, District, AddminDistrict, PotalCode and CountryRegion.

```
function GetResults(locations) {
    if (locations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            s = locations[i].Name;
            //
            var addressSplit = s.split(", ");
            addresscode = addressSplit[0]
            citycode = addressSplit[1]
            statezip = addressSplit[2]
            country = addressSplit[3]
            var statezipSplit = statezip.split(" ");
            statecode = statezipSplit[0];
            zipcode = statezipSplit[1];
            var loc_array = new Array();
            loc_array[0] = addresscode;
            loc_array[1] = citycode;
            loc_array[2] = statecode;
            loc_array[3] = zipcode;
            window.locationArray = loc_array;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parse? That's an object returned, you can access it's fields without parsing. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Ok.. I misunderstood. How do I access those fields using javascript?

Comment: I edited my question to add the code I used before to get what I needed. Can you edit your answer to reflect how I could modify the above to get the same results?

Comment: Could you show how you get `locations` argument you pass into `GetResults` function? I mean, what type of object is that?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/ on the left, click Find information(basic) and then reverse find. From there you can look at the source code and see everything.

Comment: So, actually you work with `VEMap.FindLocations` function. How is the code you pasted on pastie.org related to your question? It's not what `FindLocations` passes to `GetResults`.
Array of `VEPlace` is passed to `GetResults`, each of which only provides `Name : String` as an address. So yes, actually it is parsing :) The problem here is that `VEPlace.Name` field does not seem to have formal syntax - according to experiments it can contain any of country, city, state, zipcode, or combinations of them.

Comment: The post from Pastie.org is what I get back from Microsoft that I need to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var response = _f1299967215123();
var results = response.Results;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i)
{
    var result = results[i];

    console.log(result.BestLocation.Coordinates.Latitude);
    console.log(result.BestLocation.Coordinates.Longitude);

    console.log(result.Address.AddressLine);
    console.log(result.Address.Locality);
    // and so on
}
```